# Extract links if anchor text contains keyword

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html><head></head>
<body>
<a href='http://www.gurletins.com'>My HomePage</a>
<a href='http://www.gurletins.com/sections'>Sections</a>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Now I would like to fetch links that has keyword `Home`

Can someone tell me how to do that using BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better approach. Pass a regular expression in the [`text`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) argument:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<html><head></head>
<body>
<a href='http://www.gurletins.com'>My HomePage</a>
<a href='http://www.gurletins.com/sections'>Sections</a>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for a in soup.find_all("a", text=re.compile('Home')):
    print a['href']
```

Prints:

```
http://www.gurletins.com
```

---

Note that by default it is case-sensitive. If you need to make it insensitive, pass [`re.IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE)  flag to [`re.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.compile):

```
re.compile('Home', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> html = """
... <html><head></head>
... <body>
... <a href='http://www.gurletins.com'>My HomePage</a>
... <a href='http://www.gurletins.com/sections'>Sections</a>
... <a href='http://www.gurletins.com/home'>So nice to be home</a>
... </body>
... </html>
... """
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> for a in soup.find_all("a", text=re.compile('Home', re.IGNORECASE)):
...     print a['href']
... 
http://www.gurletins.com
http://www.gurletins.com/home
```

Comment: Is it case insensitive?

Comment: why would you need re to search for a single word?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham because it could be anywhere inside the text. Omitting the `re.compile()` would help to find only exact matches.

Comment: will it match home in the link also?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham single lower-case? By default, it is sensitive, but it is controlled with a `re.IGNORECASE` flag.

Answer (score 2):

```
html = """
<html><head></head>
<body>
<a href='http://www.gurletins.com'>My HomePage</a>
<a href='http://www.gurletins.com/sections'>Sections</a>
</body>
</html>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for i in soup.find_all("a"):
    if "HOME" in str(i).split(">")[1].upper():
        print i["href"]
http://www.gurletins.com
```